# UITextField in UISearchController BecomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a UITextField that is in a UISearchController that needs to become the FirstResponder when the view controller is shown.

On ViewDidLoad the UISearchController is built.

On ViewDidAppear I get the UITextField from the UISearchController and tell it to BecomeFirstResponder

```
public override void ViewDidLoad(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        BuildSearchController();

        SearchController.SearchBar.BecomeFirstResponder();
    }

private void BuildSearchController()
    {
        UIFont MyFont = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 20f);

        SearchController = new UISearchController(ResultsTableController)
        {
            WeakDelegate = this,
            DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false,
            WeakSearchResultsUpdater = this,
        };

        SearchController.SearchBar.ScopeButtonTitles = new string[5] { "Account", "Name", "Service Address", "Phone", "SSN" };
        UITextField SearchField = (UITextField)SearchController.SearchBar.Subviews[0].Subviews[2];

        SearchField.Font = MyFont;
        SearchController.SearchBar.ShowsCancelButton = false;
        SearchController.SearchBar.SetScopeBarButtonTitle(new UITextAttributes() { Font = MyFont }, UIControlState.Normal);
        SearchController.SearchBar.SizeToFit();
        SearchController.SearchBar.SelectedScopeButtonIndex = 1;
        SearchController.SearchBar.SetShowsCancelButton(false, false);

        UISegmentedControl TempSegControl = SearchController.SearchBar.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[1] as UISegmentedControl;
        TempSegControl.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 122, 255, 255);
        TempSegControl.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        TempSegControl.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        TempSegControl.Layer.CornerRadius = 6;
        TempSegControl.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
        SearchController.SearchBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(232, 232, 232, 255);


        SearchController.HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;

        SearchField.BecomeFirstResponder();
        TableView.TableHeaderView = SearchController.SearchBar;

        SearchController.SearchBar.WeakDelegate = this;
    }

public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        UITextField SearchBox = SearchController.SearchBar.Subviews[0].Subviews[2] as UITextField;

        if (SearchBox.CanBecomeFirstResponder)
        {
            SearchBox.BecomeFirstResponder();
        }
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }
```

The UITextField never becomes the first responder because it is not able to become the first responder. Why can the UITextField not become the first repsonder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewDidLoad` is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory but not presented to the user. 
You cannot perform a UI interaction with the object in that stage.

`UISearchController` has a delegate method which is invoked when it has been automatically presented. Use it to bring up the keyboard.

```
optional func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController){
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder();
    }
```

Comment: I moved that call to the ViewDidAppear method. The UITextField in my UISearchController still does not have the focus. When the Controller is shown I want the users to be able to begin typing without having to touch inside the UITextField

Comment: Thanks that worked. Here is the C# version of it.    [Export("didPresentSearchController:")]
        public virtual void DidPresentSearchController(UISearchController searchController)
        {
            SearchController.SearchBar.Subviews[0].Subviews[2].BecomeFirstResponder();
        }